# Grouping Fields to display Most Recent Date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a quick question that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to list end user items (just an example) with only the most recent comment displayed.

```
ID  Name    EventDate     Type
1   PC      12/12/2012    End User Items 
1   PC      11/12/2012    End User Items 
1   PC      10/11/2012    End User Items 
2   Mobile  12/12/2012    End User Items 
2   Mobile  11/01/2012    End User Items 
2   Mobile  12/12/2011    End User Items 
3   Server  12/12/2013    Server
```

So I would try something like this:

```
select * from systems where type = "End User Items" group by ID
```

But the result would still not show the latest date. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the desired output for that sample input?

Comment: you want to see the most recent comment? What field does comment refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the `MAX` date as follows?

```
SELECT  Name,
    MAX(EventDate),
    Type
  FROM  systems
  WHERE type = 'End User Items'
  GROUP BY Name, Type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subQuery to get the ID and MAX Date and then join back on your systems table with the ID and the MAX date.

```
SELECT s2.Name, s.EventDate
FROM system s2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(EventDate) EventDate
            FROM systems
            WHERE type = 'End User Items'
            GROUP BY ID) AS s on s2.ID = s.ID AND s2.EventDate = s.EventDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the columns you want to show without summarization as your GROUP BY fields.  Select those fields and the calculated summary function columns (eg. max(), sum(), count() ).

```
SELECT ID, Name, MAX(EventDate) as LastDate
  FROM  systems
  WHERE type = 'End User Items'
  GROUP BY ID, Name
```

You probably want to see ID, and Name.  Type is superfluous here, since you only want one Type.  You want to get the max() date in the group.  All fields returned must either be summary functions, or GROUP BY columns.